# AJAX POST Form using return false still refreshes

Tags: ajax, forms

I can't seem to see the issue here, this AJAX request should be pulling results from sx.php and displaying within the success, although it keeps submitting to itself???

**s.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".button").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "sx.php",
               data: $(this).closest("form").serialize(), 
               cache: false,
               success: function(data){
            $('#status').html(data);
               }
           });
          return false;
      });
   });
</script>

     <form>
           <input type="hidden" name="mid" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($result['id']); ?>" />
                <h5><?php echo htmlspecialchars($result['title']); ?></h5>
           <input type="submit" class="button" value="Go" />
     </form>
```

Im going crazy here...!

Answer (score 1):

Don't trigger the click of the button, but call the from submit event:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
return false
})
```

Comment: If there are any errors before you reach `return false` it won't prevent the normal browser form submission like you would expect. For that reason I tend to favor  `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: I prefer the return false so i don't have to pass the "event" on my function, but i'm not sure what contains exactly event variable, I never checked this. Plus, I don't want that there are errors in my code.